# How to install kivent with buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have not found any resources about that topic. kivent(kivent_core, kivent_cymunt) do not have a pip repo and they don't have a p4a recipe.

I tried specifying this in my buildozer.spec file:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
#requirements = python3,kivy,android,jnius,kivmob,plyer
requirements = python3,kivy,android,jnius,kivmob,plyer,cymunk,kivent_core


# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy
requirements.source.kivent_core = /home/home-name/Projects/kivent-master/modules/core
```

But that resulted in searching for a pypi repo, logs:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/kivent-core/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/kivent-core/ - skipping
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'kivent-core': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivent_core (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivent_core (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid kivent is not currently supported on Android, mostly because kivent itself is no longer actively maintained. Its recipes bitrotted and stopped working so we removed them.

You can make it work only by providing working recipes.